# Login status check not working codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When any user try to log on I am trying to check the status, If status is 0 then redirects back to admin.
And then if status is 1 redirects to dashboard.

I have tested it out still kept me sending me to dashboard even though status 0

**Var Dump  array(1) { ["status"]=> string(1) "0" } ***

What would be the best solution for making sure it checks my log on status.

**Model Function**

```
public function getStatus() {
    $this->db->select('status');
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends Admin_Controller {


    public function index() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_validate');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

            $this->load->view('template/common/login.tpl', $this->data);

        } else {

            $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user');

            var_dump($this->model_user->getStatus());

            // array(1) { ["status"]=> string(1) "0" } 

            exit;

            if ($this->model_user->getStatus()) {

                redirect('admin/dashboard');

            } else {

                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You have not been enabled by the webmaster. Please wait up to 24/48 hours. If you need to contact the website master email' .' '. config_item('config_email'));

                redirect('admin');

            }
        }

        }
    }

    public function validate() {
        $this->load->library('user');
        if ($this->user->login() == FALSE) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate', '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Does not match any of our database records!');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are redirecting to dashboard `irrespective` of what is returned. unless its not empty.

Comment: I tried $this->model_user->getStatus() == true and also  $this->model_user->getStatus() == 1 no luck

Comment: `$data=$this->model_user->getStatus();  if($data['status']==1) //redirect to dashboard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved I had to remove a couple things from controller, and model.

Model

```
public function getStatus() {
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
    $ret = $query->row();
    return $ret->status;
}
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends Admin_Controller {

private $error = array();

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {   

    $data['title'] = 'Administration';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_validate');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {

        $this->load->view('template/common/login.tpl', $data);

    } else {

        $this->load->model('admin/user/model_user');

        if ($this->model_user->getStatus() == 1) {

            redirect('admin/dashboard');

        } else {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You have not been enabled by the webmaster. Please wait up to 24/48 hours. If you need to contact the website master email' .' '. config_item('config_email'));

            redirect('admin');

        }

    }

}

public function validate() {

    $this->load->library('user');

    if ($this->user->login() == FALSE) {

        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate', '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Does not match any of our database records!');

        return false;

    } else {

        return true;
    }
}
}
```